# Layout file is not loading for custom page magento2

Tags: magento2, layout

I have created custom pages a lot of times, but never face such issue. I have tried 'echo' in controller action, it is working. But all this time the layout file is not loading for that page.

Here are my code files.

Controller/Customer/Test.php

```
class Test extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
   protected $_pageFactory;

   public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
   {
       $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
       return parent::__construct($context);
   }

  public function execute()
   {

       $page =  $this->_pageFactory->create();
       return $page;
   }
}
```

etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="orderbysku" frontName="orderbysku">
            <module name="Vendor_Module" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

view/frontend/layout/orderbysku_customer_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="helloworld_index_index" template="Vendor_Module::index.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Any kind of help is appreciated, i'm really having a hard time to figure it out.

Comment: Its working fine for me can you share screen shot what you are getting ?

Comment: maybe simple spell mistake causing the problem kindly look into layout filename and folder name.

Comment: @AnsarHusain It is showing  a white/blank page.

Comment: I have tried the same thing in another module, and it is working. Can't figure out the problem.

Comment: @QaisarSatti I have checked it about 10 times

Comment: Can you update the full file path names with namespace as well?

Comment: @SukumarGorai Namespaces are fine as the echo is working in controller action. I have mentioned the file path in module in question just above the code files.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create **registration.php** in app/code/Vendor/Module

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

2. Create **module.xml** in app/code/Vendor/Module/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="2.0.1" />    
</config>
```

3. Create **routes.xml** in  app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="orderbysku" frontName="orderbysku">
            <module name="Vendor_Module" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

4.Create **Test.php** in app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Customer

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Customer;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
   protected $_pageFactory;

   public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
   {
       $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
       return parent::__construct($context);
   }

  public function execute()
   {

       $page =  $this->_pageFactory->create();
       return $page;
   }
}
```

5. Create **orderbysku_customer_test.xml** in app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="helloworld_index_index" template="Vendor_Module::index.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

6. Create **index.phtml** in  app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates

```
This is test template
```

Comment: did it work now as i have created for you @wasim

Answer (score 0):

Try

> bin/magento setup:di:compile

It helped me